# I cannot implement OnTouchListener to drag a PopUp Window

Tags: java, android, draggable, popupwindow, ontouchlistener

I want to drag my PopUpWindows. So I tried to implement the demo App to drag a simple PopUp Window from here:

https://questdot.com/android-popup-floating-window-tutorial/

The problem arises when I add the listener to the view

**popVideospeedView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()**:

then **View.OnTouchListener()** appears with a red underline and warns:

*Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnTouchListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onTouch(View, MotionEvent)' in 'OnTouchListener'*

it also rejects the **@Override** saying it cannot be overriden, and also says it cannot Resolve **MotionEvent**

Also, the library **android.view.View.OnTouchListener** from:

**import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;** is unused

My code is very similar to the code that runs from the link quoted, and their mini App compiles and works fine in the Android Studio SDK. But my code rejects
the implementation of the touch listener. What could I be doing wrong?

The code for my PopUp Window implementation is:

```
public void functionVideospeedPopupWindow() {
    try {
        LayoutInflater popVideospeedLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) LMMoviesMainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popVideospeedView = popVideospeedLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popvideospeed, null);
        final PopupWindow popVideospeedPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popVideospeedView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

        popVideospeedPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorStone)));
        popVideospeedPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
        popVideospeedPopupWindow.setFocusable(false);

        Button videospeedCloseButton = (Button) popVideospeedView.findViewById(R.id.popvideospeed_closeButton);
        popVideospeedPopupWindow.showAtLocation(popVideospeedView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); // 8:Margin to the left?. 18 comienza el texto utube

        popVideospeedView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // event code...
                    return true;
                }
         });

        videospeedCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popVideospeedPopupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e){}
} // End of functionVideospeedPopupWindow()
```

The only difference that I notice with the example that runs is that their PopUp code is declared within the **onCreate** sector of the Class, while my PopUp Window code is located within a method that is started by the user later in the App. Is that a relevant difference? if so, then how or why?

Finally, in case that I add: **OnTouchListener** (or is it **View.OnTouchListener**?) in: *implements* of the Class, as in: 
*public Class ...etc. ... implements OnTouchListener*, it underlines in red and warns:

*Class 'MyMainActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onTouch(View, MotionEvent)' in 'OnTouchListener'*

I know that to implement the **OnTouchListener** interface, I should add a structure like:

*public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {...*

but how to proceed with a PopUp Window with an **onTouc**h declared outside of the PopUp method?
Thanks a lot for any ideas and for your interest.

Comment: You give quite a lot of details in your post (which is good!), but for me there remains one question: you tried to use the code in the linked project but you say you've taken a different approach in some places. So could you maybe post enough code for us to reproduce exactly your issue?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your interest. I do not know how anything else could be relevant. What I need to solve is how to enable drag on a PopUp Window that is declared inside a method. It should be doable just implementing the OnTouchListener for its View, but it doesn't work, and I cannot comprehend why.

Comment: So I could use an almost empty Activity and then click some Button and trigger this method `functionVideospeedPopupWindow() ` which does not work?

Comment: Yes, literally, within a generic Class. This method is executed within a runnable:   private Runnable popupVideospeedHandlerCodeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            functionVideospeedPopupWindow();
        }
    };   And the runnable is run in:  Handler popupVideospeedHandler = new Handler();
                    popupVideospeedHandler.postDelayed(popupVideospeedHandlerCodeRunnable, PopUpMsecsDELAY);    And the PopUp Window opens fine (without the OnTouchListener part, of course). But I cannot see how is this relevant...

Comment: Good to know. I just was going to tell you that I added your snippet to be executed onClick() of some Button (but not using a Runnable) and for me the OnTouchListener is firing. I'll use a Runnable now and get back to you

Comment: Everything is working nicely (I'm writing to Logcat in `onTouch()` ). This means I'm not able to reproduce your issue by pasting snippets of your code into mine. So if you really need help let's do this the other way round: you post enough code for a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll try to figure out what's wrong with that code.

Comment: Ok. I will try to run a minimal snippet myself, and then try to figure out what could be wrong. It could also help me to define more focused questions.

Comment: If you're not able to make your MCVE work you're welcome to come back here and ping me. And if you find out what was wrong, consider writing your own answer. Maybe it will be useful to others with a similar problem

Comment: Solved! It turns out that Android Studio wasn't adding the library for the MotionEvent when I tried with Alt+Enter. So I manually added the library: import android.view.MotionEvent;  and now View.OnTouchListener doesn't generate any warning. Thanks a lot for your help, and I hope this case can help somebody else to overcome this silly bug. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!** It turns out that Android Studio wasn't adding the library for the MotionEvent when I tried with **`Alt+Enter`**. So I manually added the **library:** `import android.view.MotionEvent;` and now `View.OnTouchListener` doesn't generate any warning. Thanks a lot for your help, and I hope this case can help somebody else to overcome this silly bug. Cheers